# Are there any machine learning applications where PRNG can be a bottleneck?

Tags: machine-learning

For example large-scale distributed reinforcement learning may requires many independent streams. And there are not so many fast pseudo random number generators, which can produce $2^{30}$ independent streams. What people use for this purpose? I assume cryptographic pseudo random number generators (easy streamable) may not always be available, and may be too slow. Could the speed of the generator matter here?

Also Monte Carlo tree search seems to be method where PRNG speed may be important, but is it? But I'm not sure wether it requires independent streams.

This two methods looks for me like could require fast and stremable PRNG, quite similarly like in large scale Monte Carlo simulations, in which efficiency and quality of PRNG is especially important.

Of coruse PRNG are used for cross-validation or stochastic gradient descent - but here they don't seem to be the bottleneck.

Comment: I understand that, in this context, PRNG stands for pseudo-random number generator. Maybe it would be good to add the full name to your question, to make it clearer.

Comment: @noe ok, I added full name in first section, now it could be clearer.